# Awk: sum of different columns different rows

Tags: bash, awk

Say I have this **input**:

```
num gene    Label   start   end
n1  g1a1    L1  28  40
n1  g1a1    L2  9   42
n1  g1a1    L2  28  90
n1  g1a1    VE  64  209
n1  g1a1    VE  83  377
n1  g1a1    VR  91  377
n1  g1a1    V   378 1516
n1  g1a1    V   475 1613
n1  g1a1    V   1378    2105

n1  g2a1    VE  10209   10590
n1  g2a1    VE  11311   11590
n1  g2a1    VR  11301   11590

n2  g1a2    VE  83  377
n2  g1a2    VR  91  377

n3  g3a1    VR  105200  105801
```

The expected **output**:

```
num gene    Label   start   end
n1  g1a1    L1  28  40
n1  g1a1    L2  28  90
n1  g1a1    VE  83  377
n1  g1a1    VR  91  377
n1  g1a1    V   378 1516

n1  g2a1    VE  11311   11590
n1  g2a1    VR  11301   11590

n2  g1a2    VE  83  377
n2  g1a2    VR  91  377

n3  g3a1    VR  105200  105801
```

I want to compare 2 numeric fields ($4 and $5) between row *n* and row(s) *n+p* according to field $3 and $2.

All start and end positions of labels ($3) are compared to the VR start or end positions by gene ($2) and by number ($1), except label L1.

So for example for n1:

```
if VR(end) = 377 then:
VE(end) = 377
V(start) = VR(end) + 1
L2(start) = VR(start) - 1
```

[Here the schema of all labels gathered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Me1dB.png)

To begin, I tried to write these awk command-line

1. using an array with labels as key to retrieve start and end positions easily of the corresponding label:

   awk '{ f[$3]=$0 ;  for (i=1 ; i <= NF ; i++)  { print i "\t" $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3  }  }'  data.txt
2. in the current row get elements from the next row:

   awk ' NR>0 {print prev "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5} {prev = $0}' input

I know how to extract information from columns but I hardly know from where to start writing an awk command-line for my comparison issue.

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: "VR is the reference" Does that mean that you need to see VR before you can decide whether the previous lines were acceptable?

Comment: Hello, I am new in fact and a newbie in IT. I am trying to reedit my craft as short and clear as possible.

Comment: @Michael Vehrs: I meant that all the positions of the other labels are compared to VR ones.
I know what I am expecting to obtain but my issue is that there are 4 fields by rows to consider (genes $2, labels $3, start $4 and endposition $5). The comparison between positions depend on labels ($3) by gene ($2).
For some labels it is the same fields that are compared (VE and VR). But for some others I have to compare $4 line n and $5 line n+p. In fact, the rows are not systematically successive.

Comment: That means you need to read the entire file in order to be sure that you have seen all the relevant data.

Comment: Yes. The file is in a tab delimited format

I have reedited my question. I hope it is clearer now

Comment: @Michael Vehrs: Yes sure. Awk does that implicitly this is why I rather went with that.

Comment: `awk` reads the whole file, but it applies the actions to the matching lines as soon as they have been read, which is something quite different.

Comment: OK. 
Actually, I need an idea on how to start this comparison issue (based on some rules set up)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something along these lines:

```
/[0-9]/  {
    key = $2 $3
    genes[$2] = 1
    if ($3 == "VR") {
        vr_start[key] = $4
        vr_end[key] = $5
        vr[key] = $0
    } else {
        c = ++count[key]
        start[key c] = $4
        end[key c] = $5
        line[key c] = $0
    }
}
END {
    for (g in genes) {
        gstart = vr_start[g "VR"]
        gend = vr_end[g "VR"]
        c = count[g "L1"]
        for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            print line[g "L1" i]
        }
        c = count[g "L2"]
        for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            if (start[g "L2" i] == gstart - 1) {
                print line[g "L2" i]
            }
        }
        c = count[g "VE"]
        for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            if (end[g "VE" i] == gend) {
                print line[g "VE" i]
            }
        }
        print vr[g "VR"]
        c = count[g "V"]
        for (i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
            if (start[g "V" i] == gend + 1) {
                print line[g "V" i]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to understand your code and I have some questions:

1) why using a regular expression at the very beginning? 

2) what is "key"? I am sorry I am not really used to write codes daily

3) is "genes" an array? so if I understand it replaces the string fields in $2 by numbers, right?

4) what would be the difference if had a first block with BEGIN {...} and nothing instead of END? I mean what is the aim?

Comment: 1) In order to exclude empty lines and the headline. 2) The `key` is simply the concatenation of `gene` and `label`. 3) It is an array, but I do not understand the rest of the question. 4) The objective is to read the entire file into various arrays before printing the matching lines. This is necessary because the lines are not consecutive, as you say.